# Retain value in a disabled input when reset button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a project code input in my form as

```
<input type="text" id="txtProjectCode" name="Project Code" class="form-control" maxlength="15" disabled="disabled" />
```

When I reset my form using my reset function

```
function resetRequestForm() {
  $("#txtProjectCode").val(userProject);
}
```

I am trying to add value again through global variable, but still it is not reflecting in the form.
Please help on this

Comment: Check if your global variable has a value using ```console.log(userProject);```. It worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where `userProject` is defined.

Comment: As @Twisty and @Rahul already told you to check whether the `userProject` has a value or not. Second thing is that your field is disabled that's why it will not work either.

Comment: userProject has value, but I don't want user to edit that Project code in UI,  I want that column to be disabled and when I reset the form, I need to retain that project code
 - @AlokMali

Comment: Make this field `readonly` instead of `disabled`. So you should be able to change its value and whenever you want you can get this value.

Comment: @AlokMali tried `readonly` as well but I could not retain the value

Comment: @Syed, please see the example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled input text

`<input type="text" id="txtProjectCode" name="Project Code" class="form-control" maxlength="15" disabled="disabled" />`

Clear Button

`<button class="clear_button" onclick ="return resetForm();" id="clearRequest">Clear</button>`

This will retain the data in the disabled input, when

- the form is cleared using a button with custom `resetForm()` function
- the button type is set as `reset'

Note:

- Data will not be retained if `readonly="readonly"` is used instead of `disabled="disabled"` (in both the cases)
- no need to feed the data again as `$("#txtProjectCode").val(userProject);` - `userProject` is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this example. It is not exactly what you are doing.

But I am only showing the way how to do it.

Here It is working with `disabled` also, but please note that disabled fields value will not post on the server end.

```js
var userProject = 'My Project';

function resetRequestForm() {
  $("#txtProjectCode").val(userProject);
}

function getValueAgain(){
  console.log($("#txtProjectCode").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtProjectCode" name="Project Code" class="form-control" maxlength="15" readonly />

<button onClick="resetRequestForm()"; >resetRequestForm</button>

<button onClick="getValueAgain()"; >getValueAgain</button>
```

Comment: My button type is reset, so value is vanishing from the screen (UI). Even if I try to feed it again using `$("#txtProjectCode").val(userProject);` in my reset function, I am not getting it in UI. Please help on this. I need to display it on the screen even after reset

Comment: @Syed, Now you are saying the actual issue. You only need to take this field `txtProjectCode` out of your form. So this input box will no longer with your form and whenever you reset your form, this field will not be blank again.

Comment: but I need it to be available in the form (UI), user should be able to see it but as a read only

Comment: You can show this in your UI, but in your HTML close your `</form>` tag before this field. You can position your input by CSS